# iOS framework and separate project have the same framework dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am creating a framework in Xcode for my iOS app which contains a large set of common classes which are used amongst several projects. Some of these classes have dependencies on other frameworks. However, there are also classes in other projects where I want to use this framework, which share some of the same framework dependencies.

To try simplify with an example:

- Framework A: has classes which require Framework B
- Project 1: includes Framework A, but has a class which requires Framework B.

I am currently including Framework B in Framework A so that my code will compile. There are two problems:

1. Once I do this, I can't include Framework B in Project 1, because there is now a duplication of classes.
2. It sounds like I'm creating an umbrella framework, which is usually discouraged.

Is there a way I can build Framework A in a way that says: "trust these frameworks will be included in any projects that use you, and don't include them yourself"?

Comment: The simplest, but still by far the ideal solution, is to 'use CocoaPods'.  See this SO questoin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23056103/handling-dependencies-for-ios-framework-project.  It'll do what you want, at the expense of having to buy into their ecosystem, and also add to compilation / build time whenever you update your dependencies (could be surprisingly often).
I'm very interested in a solution that doesn't require CocoaPods.